# Ordenar datos en un selected PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un inconveniente con una lista en en `php`. Resulta que cuando hago el `SELECT` en `MySQL` me imprime la lista tal cual, pero cuando llamo ese `SELECT` para ponerlo en una lista me lo trae ordenado alfabéticamente.

Asi es el orden en `MySQL` y es como quiero que esté:

- Córdoba
- Landeta
- Las Varillas
- etc...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así es como sale la lista en `php`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la parte del código en dónde se crea la lista en `php` (`$res_emp` es el `SELECT` de `MySQL` el cual está funcionando bien y listo en la primera imagen):

```
    $res_emp = $this->link_db_cli->query ( $sql_emp );

    //echo $res_emp;die();
    while ( $row_emp = $res_emp->fetch_array ( MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ) {
        $destino [] = $row_emp;         
    }

    $this->link_db_cli->close();
    function cmpl($a, $b) {
        return strcmp ( $a ["geol_nombre"] , $b ["geol_nombre"]);
    }

    usort ( $destino, "cmpl" );

    //$type = "<option>Seleccionar...</option>";
    foreach ( $destino as $reg ) {
        $idl = $_POST [id] . "=" . $reg [geol_id];
        $type .= "<option value='$idl'>" . $reg [geol_nombre] . "</option>";
    }

    return $type;
}
```

Y esta es la parte en `HTML`:

```
<div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="paradas" style="display: block;">
        <label for="origen"> Su Ubicación: </label> 
        <select name="sel_origen" id="origen" data-native-menu="false" onchange="javascript:CheckUbicacion()"></select>
    </div>                          
</div>
```

Comment: Estas usando bootstrap o algun otro plugin, o es un select simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema está en esta linea:

```
usort ( $destino, "cmpl" );
```

Estás ordenando el `array`. Simplemente remueve esa línea y funcionará como esperas.